# eJabberd API with OAuth2

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, ejabberd

I installed eJabberd 16.2 on my machine. I am trying to access the api through Postman. When I use Basic Auth everything is working fine.

I managed to get a token through the page:
http://localhost:5280/oauth/authorization_token?response_type=token&client_id=Client1&scope=get_roster+sasl_auth

But every time I try to access the api with the token by adding and Authorization field to headers of the request with a value of: "bearer s7rjU649vlnVZUzaGXDtNdLQ1I4r7V2R", I get error code 32: "AccessRules: Account associated to token does not have the right to perform the operation."

This is the config in **eJabberd.yml** file:

```
  - 
    port: 5280
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/http-bind": mod_http_bind
      "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
      #"/log": mod_log_http
      # ##OAuth support:
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
      # ##ReST API:
      "/api": mod_http_api

    ##  "/pub/archive": mod_http_fileserver
    web_admin: true
    http_bind: true
    http_poll: true
    register: true
    captcha: false
    commands_admin_access: 
      - allow:
        - user: "admin@HASOON"
    commands:
      - add_commands: [user, admin, open]
    oauth_expire: 3600
    oauth_access: all

    api_permissions:
      - "Admin access":
        - who:
          - admin
        - what:
          - "*"
          - "!stop"
```

Any idea why I fail to use OAuth token.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration should be :

```
  - 
    port: 5280
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
      "/api": ejabberd_http_api
    web_admin: true
    http_bind: true
    ## register: true
    captcha: false
    tls: true
    certfile: "/opt/ejabberd-16.12/conf/server.pem"

commands_admin_access: configure
commands:
  - add_commands:
    - user
oauth_expire: 31536000
oauth_access: all

api_permissions:
  - "Admin access":
    - who:
      - admin
    - what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it did not solve the problem. In fact when I added "tls: true" I couldn't call the API any more.

Comment: You're right, I thought since I could OAUTH token, that I could use token to do operations like register, but in fact I couldn't get that to work at all
I can do it only using basic authentication
I added an issue on github for that 
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/1491